# Join unrelated tables

Tags: sql-server

I want to join these two unrelated tables:

table 1

```
id   name   age
--   ----   ---
1    a      9
2    b      11
3    c      10
```

table 2

```
id   school   address
--   ------   -------
1    aa       abc
1    aa       efg
3    bb       hij
```

Desired results:

```
id   school   address   age   name
--   ------   -------   ---   ---- 
1    aa       abc       9     a
1    aa       efg       9     a
2    NULL     NULL      11    b
3    bb       hij       10    c
```

Comment: FWIW these seem like related tables to me. By "unrelated" do you just mean there isn't an explicit foreign key defined?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.school, t2.address, t1.age, t1.name
FROM dbo.table1 AS t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.table2 AS t2
ON t1.id = t2.id
ORDER BY t1.id;
```